# Show that $ \bar{X}_{k_n} ^n \rightarrow e^{cZ} \ \text{in distribution}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n,...$ be positive, i.i.d. random variables. Define $$\bar{X_n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$$.

Assume that $E(X_1)=1$, Var$(X_1)=\sigma^2 < \infty$. We need to show that if $k_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then as $n \rightarrow \infty$,
$$ \bar{X}_{k_n} ^n \rightarrow e^{cZ} \ \text{in distribution}$$

where $Z \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, if $\frac{n^2}{k_n} \rightarrow c^2$.

I was trying to look at the MGF by expanding:

$$M_{\bar{X}_{k_n} ^n}(t) = 1 + \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{k_n} X_i)^n}{k_n ^n} .t + \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{k_n} X_i)^{2n}}{2 k_n ^{2n}}. t^2 + ...$$

But I could not infer anything from here! Other approaches to crack this?

Comment: If $e^{cZ}$ is a log-normal distribution then it will not have a moment generating function

Comment: Use characteristic functions.

Comment: But even if I use CF, I can't prove the fact that the distribution goes to $e^{cZ}$

Comment: Here is a non-rigorous handwaving argument:  $\sqrt{k_n}(\bar X_{k_n}-1)$ converges to $N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution by the central limit theorem so $\frac{n}{c}(\bar X_{k_n}-1)$  might do the same. If $\bar X_{k_n}=1+ \frac{Zc}{n}$ with $Z$ almost having a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution then since $(1+\frac xn)^n \to  e^x$ as $n$ increases, we have $\bar X_{k_n}^n \to e^{Zc}$ in distribution which is the result we want.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$
\bar{X}_{k_n} ^n=\left(1+\frac 1n\frac{n}{\sqrt{k_n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k_n}}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}\left(X_i-\mathbb E\left[X_i\right]\right) \right)^n
$$
and letting $Z_n= \frac{n}{\sqrt{k_n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k_n}}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}\left(X_i-\mathbb E\left[X_i\right]\right)$,the central limit theorem and the assumtion on $k_n$ gives $Z_n\to N(0,c^2\sigma^2)$.

To conclude, it suffices to notice that if $Z_n\to Z$ in distribution, then $\left(1+Z_n/n\right)^n\to e^Z$ in distribution.